# how to cluster markers using angularjs and leaflet

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am using AngularJS and leaflet for my project where lots of markers making the map messy, I would love to markerCluster with angular, I followed [this](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) but I am unable to find `leaflet.markercluster.js` in the code.

Comment: There is a [marker clustering example](https://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/markers-clustering-example.html), or are you looking for a different solution?

Comment: you need to include the marker clustering plugin for leaflet.js separately  before you can use it. [link](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) . Make sure you use the version corresponding to the version of your leaflet library.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Leaflet.markercluster plugin as many other plugins, here http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html